# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '../database/db' when i try to run my code

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

so i was trying to implement a database for my discord bot but when it try to call on it all i get is

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '../database/db'

heres the bit thats failing

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
let connection;
require('dotenv').config();

///Token for discord bot
(async () => {
    connection = await require('../database/db');
    await bot.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
   })();
```

and heres my file structure

[image]

i tried installing mysql2 globally to see if that work help and it didnt :(

EDIT: [image]

someone asked what the file inside database looked like

Comment: What does `..\database\db` look like? What file is the code you’ve provided above sourced from?

Comment: require expects a file, not a directory. You have to set the path to your database file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didnt give us enough info i cant really help but if your file name your trying to get is `db` and your file name is index.js then this should work

```
connection = await require('./database/db');
```

NOTE : if this doesnt work please add more screenshots / more info about your file locations

Comment: this worked thank you. i guess i was trying to go too far into the files?

Comment: @CarrymesenpaiUwU Now i realise that your problem was that you added one extra .